# Android: sleep doesn't work with UI changes

Tags: android, sleep

I'm making simple quiz app, and now there is a problem with waiting.
When user clicks one of four possible answers, it should change to orange and after two seconds to red or green (right or wrong answer). Here is part of my code:

```
public void clickButton(View v) {
    changeButton(v, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_orange));
    try {
        //Thread.sleep(2000);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
    } catch ( InterruptedException r ) {}

    changeButton(v, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_red));
}
```

I tried thread sleep or timeunit sleep, but in both cases, the button changes to default white "clicked" phase and after two seconds to red - completely skipping orange part. I checked other colors, so that is definetely not problem in those color xml files. Problem is probably somewhere in that sleep, but i don't know what i should use to delay red color and still se orange.
thx for advice

Comment: you shouldn't sleep on the main thread, have a look at View.postDelayed()

Comment: actually you MUST NOT sleep on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@panini is right, you should't sleep on the main thread, use another thread instead, try something like this, doesn't tested so I don't know if it will work but is an idea:

```
public void clickButton(final View v) {
    changeButton(v, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_orange));
    v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            changeButton(v, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_red));
        }
    }, 2000);


}
```

Maybe you need to force the thread to run in the UI, try it anyway. If that doesn't work you can always use a AsyncClass.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to post delayed `Runnables` to the UI thread is to pass a message to the `Handler` of the UI thread.

For example:

```
 new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        changeButton(v, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_orange));
      }}, 2000);
```